# JPA: Read and persist in one transaction while blocking Read in different thread

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, jpa, transactions

My use case are two entities in 1..N relationship, let's say Box and Items in Box. Box has an attribute "capacity" which specify how much Items I can have in Box.

What I'm actually doing. I select count of all Items in Box and when the number of Items is less than the Box.capacity I persist the Item.

Problem is when I access my method concurrently. Calling method twice in a same time will cause that both reads can be run concurrently and when it comes for write phase, both thread write the Item into database.

My code:

```
@Entity
public class Box {
    private int capacity;
}

@Entity
public class Item {
    @ManyToOne
    Box box;
}

@Stateless
public class BoxManager {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public Item persistItem(Item item) {
        Box box = item.getBox();
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(i) FROM Item i WHERE i.box = :box");
        query.setParameter("box", box);

        int itemCount =  ((Number)typedQuery.getSingleResult()).intValue();

        // We can simulate concurrent problem putting Thread.sleep() here.

        if (itemCount < box.getCapacity()) {
            return em.persist(item);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm calling method `persistItem` concurrently.

The question is how can I prevent another thread to read the incorrect number of Items before the first thread persist the first Item?

Problematic scenario is:

```
Thread 1: Reads count of items
Thread 2: Reads count of items
Thread 1: Writes Item to database
Thread 2: Also Writes Item to database
```

Or is there any better way how to handle this? How to check count of entity and persist it without the concurrency problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the ORM frameworks will not supports your own business logic.  i would prefer to use the java lock mechanism , either new Lock specs or old good way of doing using synchronized block by covering the read and write operation in block.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot it could be that simple and was thinking about complicated database locking.

Comment: It could work, but you have to check some issues, for example what object's are you lock??, if you lock or sychronize the method you don't have concurrency the method will execute once at the same time, other case is if your select return different values for two different calls but you lock the block sentence and not the entities returned by the query  you always lock the objects regardless the values. That's why I don't recommend you to use this method I suggest you to check the locking mechanism of JPA that were created for something

Answer (score 3):

With JPA you can add locking mechanisms, Since version 2.0 you have support for optimistic and pessimistic locking, In the optimistic version you can add a version column that allows to check if the correct version of the entity is changing, in the other hand pessimistic lock use database locking sentences. In your case you can set a block in the query with `Query.setLockMode`.

In this [article](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/locking_and_concurrency_in_java) you can have more information

Comment: I've decided to go the easiest way and use synchronized block. But thank you very much for article, I will definitely learn something from it.